When clicked on Font Amesome icon, the hyperlink doesn't work
The website is https://alloutcreative.com/
This is the code:
                            <div class="mil-team-card mil-up mil-mb-30">
                                <img src="img/faces/Eugen.jpg" alt="Team member">
                                <div class="mil-description">
                                    <div class="mil-secrc-text">
                                        <h5 class="mil-muted mil-mb-5">Eugen Kelemen</a></h5>
                                        <p class="mil-link mil-light-soft mil-mb-10">Founder, CEO, Videography, Photography, Visual Effects</p>
                                        <ul class="mil-social-icons mil-center">
                                            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/eugen.jk/" target="_blank" class="social-icon"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

It just redirects me to https://alloutcreative.com/eugen.jk/ and not the wanted link.

Your code has a nesting error <h5 class="mil-muted mil-mb-5">Eugen Kelemen</a></h5> if you remove the orphaned closing </a> tag it should work

This is working for me
<a href="#" 
 onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com/eugen.jk/', 
 '_blank')" class="social-icon">
 <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</a>


Try This, working for me.
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
</body>
</html>

